# What coordinates do I use to edit multiple instances of an object as if I was editing one at a time?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools, scale

So I have these teeth.  Let's say, I wanted the selected ones to look more like the unselected one.  (Perhaps it's too thin, but still.)
[image]

Whenever I try to scale the center vertices in at one, it always leans them all in the same direction, like so:
[image]

This is really cool, but without understanding why it does that, it would perhaps be difficult to replicate the effect for anything useful.  I would much appreciate it if someone could explain how to resize these teeth at once, as if each selection were independent (ie, had it's own origin I believe.)

Hypothetical bonus points for anyone who can explain the exact rules that scale is following here - that effect is cool.  Source is [here](https://youtu.be/qsmnewI9SXE?t=1697).

Comment: Ctrl . (dot) to activate the *Individual Origins* Pivot point.

Comment: @Leander And you just opened up my life to the wide and wonderful world of "pivot point" (I probably knew about it a long time ago, but I've been to busy to stick with blender faithfully)